# Binary SMS not working

Tags: android, sms

I am sending a binary SMS from one emulator to another, both Galaxy Nexus API 22. Message gets sent, but three problems arise:

1. On sending emulator, default SMS app displays the SMS like a normal sent text message.
2. On receiving emulator, a notification pops when SMS is received, and the SMS appears in the default message app like a normal received text message.
3. My app does not receive the binary SMS.

Sender (main activity onCreate):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SmsManager.getDefault().sendDataMessage(
                "5556",
                null,
                (short) 2345,
                "This is a binary SMS!".getBytes(),
                null, 
                null);
    }
});
```

Manifest entry for receiver:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".Receiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
        <data
            android:scheme="sms"
            android:host="*"
            android:port="2345" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver is a copy of a [binary SMS receiver from a tutorial](http://codetheory.in/android-sms/).